# Magento 2: Setup domain for a multi-store

Tags: magento2, multistore, url

I want to assign a new domain 'example.ai' to my current multistore 'www.mywebsite.ca/mystore/'

I tried adding 'example.ai' on storeview level to System->configuration->General->Web-> Base URLs & Base URLs (secure) but it didnt work.

My hosting provider is cloudways.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.